# Nodejs fetching rows from google spreadsheet returns object undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to get values from google spreadsheet  which returns value as undefined. Here is my code

```
app.get('\userdetails',(req,res) => {
    Var doc = new GoogleSpredsheet('sheetId');
       doc.useServiceAccountAuth(cred, function(err) {  
          doc.getRow(1, function (err, row){ console.log(row);});
    });
});
```

In cred i have my credentials
And as sheetId i have passed the id of sheet that has edit access

Comment: What value do you get from the console.log?

Comment: As @Saurabh Mistry suggests, you have to console log errors, to try to understand the error cause...

Answer (score 1):

you need to check , if something error you got in console log like this :

```
app.get('userdetails',(req,res) => {
    Var doc = new GoogleSpredsheet('sheetId');
       doc.useServiceAccountAuth(cred, function(err) {  
          if(!err){
              doc.getRow(1,function(error,row){
                  if(!error && row){
                    console.log(row);
                  }else{
                     console.log('ERROR IN getRow :'+error);
                  }
               });

          }else{
             console.log('ERROR IN useServiceAccountAuth : '+err);
          }
    });
});
```